# Plasmo framework and Material UI in content UI script

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, material-ui

I'm using Plasmo to make a browser extension with React and I would like to utilize the MUI library. I am able to get the components to work in the popup script, however, in my content UI scripts, I am unable to get the styling to show up (i.e. I just get a plain HTML button instead of a MUI-styled button).

How can I get the correct styles from the MUI components in my component script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check out this example](https://github.com/PlasmoHQ/examples/blob/5a93025794b6a748df8dccabdb926dfead3f114d/with-mui/content.tsx)

Here's the outline of what you need to do:

`npm i @emotion/cache @emotion/react`

```
import createCache from "@emotion/cache"
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react"

const styleElement = document.createElement("style")

const styleCache = createCache({
  key: "plasmo-mui-cache",
  prepend: true,
  container: styleElement
});

export const getStyle = () => styleElement;

const MuiThemedContent = () => (
  <CacheProvider value={styleCache}>
    ... mui component
  </CacheProvider>
);
export default MuiThemedContent;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this  I actually had to talk to some Plasmo devs and they also linked me to that. I should've updated it here, but you've done it for me!